# Creating pretty printed incrementally generated XML from python with lxml and xmlfile

Tags: python, xml, lxml, pretty-print

I am using lxml's [Incremental XML generation](https://lxml.de/api.html#incremental-xml-generation) to generate XML on the fly.  However although chunks of XML elements you add to the output can (and are) pretty printed if requested, there is an area around the root element where this goes wonky.

The test code I am using looks like this:-

```
from lxml import etree


def writer(filename):
    with etree.xmlfile(filename, encoding="ISO-8859-1", close=True) as xf:
        xf.write_declaration()
        xf.write_doctype("<!DOCTYPE myDoctype>")
        with xf.element("myDoc", version="1.0"):
            while True:
                el = yield
                xf.write(el, pretty_print=True)
                xf.flush()


output = writer("test.xml")
next(output)

for x in range(3):
    el = etree.Element("data", number=str(x))
    se = etree.SubElement(el, "item")
    se.text = f"item {str(x)}"
    output.send(el)
```

and this gives an output looking like this:-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<!DOCTYPE myDoctype>
<myDoc version="1.0"><data number="0">
  <item>item 0</item>
</data>
<data number="1">
  <item>item 1</item>
</data>
<data number="2">
  <item>item 2</item>
</data>
</myDoc>
```

where line #3 has the root and first data element together on the same line.

Unfortunately for the application I am building, I cannot rely on existing consumers of this data to be in any way sane (or not parsing the stuff with regex etc) so really want the line spacing, and ideally the pretty print indents to look just like the previous generator.

Any ideas how to assert the pretty printing of the output more thoroughly?

Comment: Similar unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56000781/407651

Comment: Ah that referenced question gives me a clue as to how to at least get rid of the root and first contained tag being on the same line - I hadn't realised you could add a `xf.write("\n")` after opening the root element.

That will work sufficiently well for me.